# Overwriting an array in Numpy function Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, random

I am trying to write a `numpy` function that iterates with itself to update the values of its function. If for example `Random_numb` was equal to `[50, 74, 5, 69, 50]`. So the calculations would go like, `10* 50 = 500`  for the first calculation, with the equation `Starting_val = Starting_val * Random_numb`. The Starting_Val would equal to `500` so for the second calculation it would go as `500 * 74 = 37000`. Updating the `Startin_Val` to `37000` from `500`. Iterating through the `Random_numb` as it does the calculations, using element 1: `50` for calculation 1 and element 2 `74` for calculation 2 and so on. The calculations would go on until the end of the `Random_numb` array.

```
import numpy as np
Starting_val = 10
Random_numb = random.randint(100, size=(5))
Starting_val = Starting_val * Random_numb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you're looking for [`prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html):

```
import numpy as np

Starting_val = 10
Random_numb = np.array([50, 74, 5, 69, 50])

Random_numb.prod(initial=Starting_val)
#638250000
```

If you're interested in the multiplied values of the array it'll be [`cumprod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html):

```
Starting_val * Random_numb.cumprod()
# array([      500,     37000,    185000,  12765000, 638250000])
```

Comment: Thank is there a way I could perform more advanced arithmetic's with multipication division and addition like `Starting_val = Starting_val + Starting_val * Random_numb/10`

Comment: what do you need in the end: just one value (like in `prod` above) or the whole array (like in `cumprod`)? It would be best you provide the desired output for the example.

Comment: I have posted a new question about it I would appreciate it If you could take a look and perhaps it is more clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091981/iterating-a-numpy-array-through-arithmetic-functions

Answer (score 1):

Here you are just multiplying the Starting_val with your array of random numbers. You are not updating Starting_val each time. Try out the below code

```
for i in range(len(Random_numb)):
    Random_numb[i] *= Starting_val
    Starting_val = Random_numb[i]
```

Hope this solves your query!

Comment: I am trying not to use for loops and use numpy instead as it is much faster, but thank you.