# Iterating a Numpy array through arithmetic functions

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, iteration

In the code I have gotten from my previous issue: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66085055/overwriting-an-array-in-numpy-function-python/66087958?noredirect=1#comment116849335_66087958) I could use iterations whilst modifying the a value of multiplication. I want to use the `.prod` function but with iterations of multiplication, division and addition. The calculations will go as follows, for the first calculation `10 + 10 *50/100 = 15`  with the equation `(Starting_val + Starting_val * Random_numb/100)`. The first element in `Random_numb`  is 50 and `Starting_val` is updated to the value of 15. So for the second calculations it will be `15 + 15 *74/100 = 26.1` The value of the `Starting_val` is updated from 15 to 26.1 in the second calculation. I do not how to iterate this function with numpy. I wish to not use a `for loop` for this function.

```
import numpy as np

Starting_val = 10
Random_numb = np.array([50, 74, 5, 69, 50])

Random_numb.prod(initial=Starting_val)
Starting_val + Starting_val * Random_numb/100
```

Expected Output:

```
[15, 26.1, 27.405, 46.314, 69.471 ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `[15, 26.1, ...]` or only the last updated value for starting value?

Comment: I will update the issue and print an expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple artithmetic transformations give you

```
Starting_val * np.cumprod(Random_numb / 100 + 1)
```

Result:

```
array([15.      , 26.1     , 27.405   , 46.31445 , 69.471675])
```